# Magic square from specific set of numbers

Tags: magic-square

I need to know if the following set of numbers can be used to make a magic square:

0,1,4,5,6,9

Any of the numbers can be used multiple times and you can use as many or as few of the numbers in the set as you would like...

Why? Because every number squares to those numbers as the last digit.

0 -> 0 -> 0
1,9 -> 1,81 -> 1
2,8 -> 4,64 -> 4
3,7 -> 9,49 -> 9
4,6 -> 16,36 -> 6
5 -> 25 -> 5

So that is 0,1,4,9,6,5,6,9,4,1,0 as they appear in order of the last digit of any number squared or 0,1,4,5,6,9 in order from least to greatest...

The reason?

Making a magic square of squared numbers... this is my proof it can't be done but I need it more accurately described.

Then there is making it all the same last number and/or its pair and/or a 0 (i.e. only numbers ending in 0,1,9 or 0,2,8 etc)...

I suspect none of this is possible because tic tac toe and cat's games etc says the last digit never adds up EXCEPT in transinfinite numbers - i.e. take any magic square and get the square root of all the numbers and turn those numbers into transinfinite numbers (hyperreals/surreal from irrational by infinity divided by some factor of 10?) by removing the decimal point making infinitely long numbers that add up for sure...

So first I need to prove you can't use 0,1,4,5,6,9 I'm a magic square which will prove it has to be the same last digit (as in the last digit from a number squared ending in 1 or 9 etc or 2 and 8 etc and/or with numbers ending in 0) and then I will just have to prove that it never will add up which I'm seeing you have to get larger and larger numbers to get closer and closer hence the Transinfinite...

But also considering 10101 as a sum of 100² 10² and 1² and seeing what I can do to maybe make a 123,454,321 magic sum workout kinda deal but I have might doubts...

Comment: And Sallows square of squares failed cuz it used 4,6, and 9 and the diagonal that doesn't add up each last digit squares to 9 which is why that diagonal has 9+9+9 on the last digit instead of 4+6+9 like all the other directions i.e. ABC can't be evenly distributed on a 3x3 without one of the 8 ways being messed up and same with AB like tic tac toe... which also messes up 0,1,9 and 1,9 pairing kinda or high, low, medium because they are ABC or AB so yeah doesn't distribute evenly and then if you just go with one number you are limited in range before the number of digits increase - doubles sq'd

Comment: Without any further restrictions, you can just  take all values to be $0$.

Comment: Yes, so then a magic square of squares would be like 20² + 40² + 60² and so on... can ya do that? A 3x3 that adds up every way with squares? And yes my dad made the same joke of making them all the same number and it turns out that is likely the answer BUT IN RE the last digit! Of the number squared. BUT still to prove that you must disprove a normal magic square with mixed numbers only using 0,1,4,5,6,9 - understand?

Comment: Do you mean that the numbers must be distinct and that the *digits* must come from 0,1,4,5,6,9?

Comment: The numbers ONLY have to come from the set [0,1,4,5,6,9] and I suspect it only works if they are not distinct i.e. all the same...

Comment: I checked the all numbers ending in 0 - doesn't work... makes the same problem actually... 90 20 and 40 for example and 20 70 and 60 - you know it's XX00 but you know the XX won't add up because 9,2, and 1, is 1,4,and1 squared last digit and 2,7,and 6 is 4,9,and6 squared last digit...

Comment: OK, so there are six trivial solutions, and you want to know if there are any others?

Comment: Yes - non trivial ones

Comment: Still unclear because you are sometimes mentioning numbers with multiple digits.

Comment: Since x0² + x0² + x0² isn't working I was thinking 10101 or 10001 or 111 etc in combination to make like a 123454321 after squared etc... have my doubts...

Comment: OK so ANY NUMBER x1 x2 x3 etc squared is x1 x4 x9 you see?

Comment: I.e. 0, 1/9, 2/8, 3/7, 4/6, 5 ending digit of a number that gets squared becomes 0,1,4,5,6, or 9 on the last digit and then gets added - if they don't add up on the last digit they are a different number so the number doesn't matter just the last digit

Comment: I.e. can you make a magic square with 0,1,4,5,6,9 is the same as can you make a magic square of squares...

Comment: Let me know if you come up with something...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "this is a magic sqaure of square challenge for 1000 euro and a bottle of champagne" and we [do not allow puzzles from contests](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1675/69582)

Comment: @bobble I'm not sure that applies, because (1) An open challenge is different from a time-limited contest (which is what that link describes), (2) This isn't asking for the solution to the problem, just help with one step, (3) Even questions that do meet the criteria in the link aren't meant to be closed, just locked until the contest period has ended.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain There's a [later update](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7203/69582) to remove the time-limit requirement.

Comment: Sorry about that - didn't realize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a $3\times 3$ matrix with entries in $\{0,1,4,5,6,9\}$, with each row, column, and both diagonals having the same sum.  Via integer linear programming I found $14$ solutions, including the $6$ trivial ones.  Here are the $8$ nontrivial ones, where $x\in\{1,4,6,9\}$:

> \begin{pmatrix}5&x&10-x\\10-x&5&x\\x&10-x&5\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}10-x&x&5\\x&5&10-x\\5&10-x&x\end{pmatrix}

Explicitly, the integer linear programming formulation is as follows.  For $(i,j)\in [3] \times [3]$ and $k\in\{0,1,4,5,6,9\}$, let binary decision variable $y_{ijk}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ takes value $k$. Let nonnegative integer decision variable $s$ be the common sum (**not** constrained to be $15$).  The constraints are
\begin{align}
\sum_k y_{ijk} &= 1 &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{j,k} k y_{ijk} &= s &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\label2 \\
\sum_{i,k} k y_{ijk} &= s &&\text{for all $j$} \tag3\label3 \\
\sum_i k y_{iik} &= s \tag4\label4 \\
\sum_i k y_{i,4-i,k} &= s \tag5\label5
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} assigns exactly one value to each cell.
Constraint \eqref{2} forces each row to have sum $s$.
Constraint \eqref{3} forces each column to have sum $s$.
Constraints \eqref{4} and \eqref{5} force the two diagonals each to have sum $s$.

Comment: Doesn't work check diagonal 5+5+5

Comment: It sums to $15$, just like the other diagonal and all rows and columns.

Comment: Wow! Good job! Okay so ya did it!

Comment: So now you need:

Comment: 1,9 / 3,7 / 5 ending digits in row 1 and 3,7 / 5 /1,9 second row and 5 / 1,9  / 3,7 in the last row OF THE ending digits of numbers to be squared that add up by row and column

Comment: Anyway this is a magic sqaure of square challenge for 1000 euro and a bottle of champagne

Comment: Yes, that is another solution.  It turns out that all eight nontrivial solutions have $5,5,5$ on one diagonal.

Comment: Well I believe that and all the same last digit after squaring are the only solutions... but I thought there wasn't even that before u told me so I'll have to keep an open mind... on this square of squares problem... that's the next challenge of it...

Comment: I marked it as accepted but I wanted to know how you got to the answer as well. I would assume that it's because the magic summer is fifteen which is a common magic sum for 3x3 magic squares right?

Comment: Or if you could give me the 8 - a 3x3 is 9 squares that add up 8 ways so its interesting there are 8 solutions.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I can solve it now...

Comment: Row 1: 25², 17², 31² Row 2: 31², 25², 17² Row 3: 17², 31², 25² is my progress so far or my first square of squares...

Comment: Now I gotta try to use all different numbers but keep the last digit of them consistent i.e. 1,3,7,9, and 5 or 2,4,6,8 and 5...